# Invoke another lamba pass info to it and read the info on the lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to pass info from one lambda(function 1) to another lambda(function 2).
I know with boto3 I would use this to invoke function 1

```
load = {
    'id': 25,
    'Info': 'Information',
}
json_load = json.dumps(load)
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='string',
    Payload=json_load,
)
```

How would I go about reading json_load in function 2 though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you should use `InvocationType='RequestResponse'` and pass the data via `ClientContext`.

From [Lambda.invoke() doesn't send client context · Issue #1388 · aws/aws-sdk-js](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1388):

> It looks like you need to put the data you wish to send under the key custom in the object that gets JSON.stringify'd and base64 encoded. For example, with the following client code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var la = new AWS.Lambda({ region: 'us-west-2' });
var ctx = {
    custom: { foo: 'bar' },
    client: { snap: ['crackle', 'pop']},
    env: { fizz: 'buzz' },
};
la.invoke({
    FunctionName: 'contextPrinter',
    ClientContext: AWS.util.base64.encode(JSON.stringify(ctx)),
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    Payload: JSON.stringify({ baz: 'quux' })
}, function (err, data) { return console.log(err, data); });
```

> and the following lambda:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("context", context.client_context)
    print("client", ', '.join(i for i in dir(context.client_context.client) if not i.startswith('__')))
    print("custom", context.client_context.custom)
    print("env", context.client_context.env)
```

> I get the following log output:

```
('context', <__main__.ClientContext object at 0x7f5705898170>)
('client', 'app_package_name, app_title, app_version_code, app_version_name, installation_id')
('custom', {u'foo': u'bar'})
('env', {u'fizz': u'buzz'})
```

The client context contains data about the client, but data under the `custom` or `env` keys is made available to the lambda function.